# I have a date in the format of Mar-19. I need to select range for the entire month in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I have a date in the format of Mar-19 as in March, 2019. I need to select a range for the entire month of March in SQL Server query using only Mar-19 (MMM-yy). The output should be:
start date is >= '03/01/2019' and end date is <= '03/31/2019'. I need to factor in the months of the year with various number of days in the month as well.

Comment: Don't tell me you store date using `varchar`.

Comment: I'm using an Ajax Calendar Picker in an ASP.NET Webforms application. I'll pass the parameter to a stored procedure where the date is in date format but I may need to do some conversion in c# before passing the parameter. I was hoping it was possible to do in my stored proc though.

Comment: Stop and think about your goal. You said "Mar-19" is this year. So what happens next year (you know, when your app is actually being used for work) when this same value is passed? Does it now mean Mar 19 2020? What happens when you want to run your report for last year? Like in January? Short answer - you pass a string to your procedure in a known, documented format and the procedure does the conversion into actual date boundaries. But you really, REALLY, need to think about your implementation before you relying on such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you called your procedure as `EXEC dbo.SomeProc @Year, @Month`, inside your procedure, you can get your result similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, MyDateColumn) = @Year AND DATEPART(MONTH, MyDateColumn) = @Month
```

Comment: I'm getting Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int. MyDateColumn is a datetime2 format. Should that matter?

Comment: Also, here is the C# code that I'm using to convert the date before passing to the stored proc: `DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtPeriod.Text);
                int month = datetime.Month;
                int year = datetime.Year;`

Comment: This is not the section of code that is causing the error.  There's nothing about `DATETIME2` in these code.  It must be on the SP side.